# Unable to retrieve youtube username

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I do have channelId of a channel. But now I want to get the username of that channel (NOT TITLE). I have used following request and I got many details like likes, views, title, description but it is not providing with the username.
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics&id=UCgT2O93IiQT3XdpQYI6KDYQ&maxResults=10&key=123456789
P.S I've used my api_key properly.

Comment: Isn't the `items[0]/snippet/customUrl` entry returned by your request what you are looking for? In your case it returns `@sushantbhandari9275`.

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking all the possible data which can be included in the response of [channel API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource), I can say that it is not possible to retrieve the username as of now. And I don't think there is an alternative way of doing that.

Let's hope they include it in the future.